# how to show n record based on a text feature criteria & n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4 rows in SQL MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, social-networking, ms-access-2013

I am looking for some help with `SQL MS Access 2013`. What I need is to query/report on: search for combined text features like ? and 'how' in a table with post and comments then if in comment n then display that row n and the next 4 rows up, so n, n-1, n-2, n-3, n-4 (due to time sequence in e.g., Facebook posts and comments), and another or combined query/report if in post n so display n, find the first comment down the record ID and also display first comment n+1, then n+2, n+3 and n+4 from the time sequence for Post and Comments in a social network

e.g.

```
P1
C4
C3
C2
C1
```

So if  I search for combined text features like ? and 'how' in C2 and it exists then show C2 and C3 and C4

So if  I search for combined text features like ? and 'how' in P1 and it exists then show `P1 and C1,C2,C3 and C4`

Comment: Can you actually show example data than these generalized placeholders? First you mention n, n+1, n+2, ... rows then later you seem to mention columns, P1, C1, C2, ... What output do you need? And what differentiates P's and C's. Finally please attempt the query where criteria as Like ? And 'how' are not very clear.

Comment: how can I show record n based on a criteria and then the 4 rows closest to n

Comment: I will try to implement for some data, but want to know if it is possible

Comment: Yes, it is possible with [TOP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) clause. In fact, I have a solution for you in draft form but re-reading your post, I do not know what exactly you need.

Comment: It is quite possible. Give an example of data and show result you expect.

Comment: If you use a sequence (should exist in any database) then it will be very easy to get the 4 next or previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your tables look like, but I think this is what you might be trying to achieve in pseudocode:

1. Find the post/comment/entry records which meet your condition, e.g.

```
SELECT [ID] FROM [Table] WHERE ([Field] LIKE "*searchterm*")
```

2. For each of the matching results, return `n + m` sequential results, where `n` is a single row returned by the above query and `m` is the number of sequential results you want to see after that. Here is a way to do that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[ID], B.*
FROM ((
   SELECT [ID] FROM [Table] WHERE ([Field] LIKE "*searchterm*")
) AS A
INNER JOIN [Table] AS B
ON A.[ID] = B.[ID] OR
ON (A.[ID] + 1) = B.[ID] OR
ON (A.[ID] + 2) = B.[ID] OR
ON (A.[ID] + 3) = B.[ID] OR
ON (A.[ID] + 4) = B.[ID])
ORDER BY A.[ID], B.[ID]
```